# what is there equivalent to rollback transaction of SQL in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

if in a transaction any error occurs

sql will rollback the process.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

 COMMIT

 IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK

END TRANSACTION
```

How i can do the same in asp.net C#?

Comment: What do you want to rollback?

Comment: Take a look at the [TransactionScope Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: By the way, the code yo posted looks like it will always commit the transaction, because COMMIT is called before the if check.

Comment: @Tim It starts with "BEGIN TRANSACTION", so it commits the nested transaction, then possibly rolls back the outer transaction. (This is horribly confusing, so don't do it.)

Comment: @hvd - Ah, thanks.  I forgot about nested transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet shows the general idea:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
using (SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("command text", connection) { Transaction = transaction })
{
    connection.Open();
    try
    {
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
        throw;
    }
}
```

If the command fails to execute and throws any exception, the transaction will be rolled back.

Answer (score 2):

Check below to see how to implement Implicit Transaction using Transaction Scope which will give you transaction in C#. If you call the Complete method for the `TransactionScope` it will be commited otherwise rolledback.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee818746(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I don't really find your question clear enough. Here is something I would like to share. I assume you are asking this.

In SQL, imagine something like this (not really syntax):

```
begin transaction
insert into table X y= 1, z =2
insert into table A b =1, c =2
commit
```

Now, imagine there is no column b in table A so this transaction would not work.

To do same in ASP.Net where you have close to no control over actual DB transactions, combination of try/catch and transaction is what I will suggest. Not because it is the right way but just because it can do what you want.

Again, this is not the right way. Tell more about your problem and more people can help.